# How to proxy between 2 apps containing shared paths in a DRY way

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm a newbie with `Ngnix` and I am looking for some advice to avoid repeating location blocks and preserve functionality.
I used to have one react application `react.mydomain.cc`
On my `Nginx` configuration file I was proxing everything from `/` to `react.mydomain.cc`

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @approute;
}

location @approute {

    proxy_ssl_server_name on;

    set $react "http://react.mydomain.cc";

    proxy_pass $react$request_uri;
}
```

Now, I want to replace part of the old application with a new one without having to make changes to the old.

The logic would be.

If the users goes to `www.mydomain.cc` he should be proxied to the new app `http://new-react.mydomain.cc`
The same other paths like:

```
/about
/contact
/blog
/whoiam
/photos
```

and a few more

These pages are also active through the other subdomain `http://react.mydomain.cc/about` but not accessible through nginx domain, `www.mydomain.cc`

If the user goes to

```
/notes
/playground
/app/*
/internal/*
```

he should be proxied to the old app.

Example: the user goes to `www.mydomain.cc/notes` and he is proxied to `http://react.mydomain.cc/notes`. Then he click on the link `/about` and he is proxied to the new app `http://new-react.mydomain.cc/about` even when the old app has `/about`.

Can anyone help me to avoid having to repeat 20 times location blocks? I'm trying to achieve the same but in a cleaner way.
Please, let me know if edition is needed to clarify. Remember I am new.

Comment: In my Opinion, you could use a `map` to do it